# for loop showing error(unsupported operand error) in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am getting this error when i trying to parse through a for loop

```
pages=soup.find('span',{'class':'pagnDisabled'})
if pages==None:
    print 'None'
elif pages!=None:
    for i in range(2, pages + 1):
       print i
```

I am getting this error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Tag' and 'int'
```

Comment: `pages` isn't an int. Were you expecting an int? If so, why?

Comment: You want `pages.length` most likely.

Comment: @user2357112 the number iam getting as the value of `pages` is `37`

Comment: @FazeelaAbuZohra *How are you getting it*? Try `int(pages) + 1` then.

Comment: @TigranSaluev i have tried that before but no luck

Comment: why not doing a "for i in pages"?

Comment: @FazeelaAbuZohra  How you can get 37, because type of pages is a Tag?

Comment: Beautiful Soup documentation tells us that the result of `soup.find` is either `None` or a `Tag`. What are you trying to iterate over?

Comment: print `pages` and see what the output is.

Comment: A style hint: If you are checking for `== None`, there is no need to check again in an `elif:` - just do `else:`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.find()` returns a `Tag` object which implements a `__len__` but when you try to add a `Tag` object with an `int` it will *not* try to use the length of the tag so you will have to explicitly call it with `len(pages)`, which will give you back the length of a Tag's contents.

Also, `.find()` only returns 1 Tag. You want the `.find_all()` method instead.

Answer (score 1):

soup.find() return a Tag. Maybe you must used soup.findall() method instead of soup.find() like this:

```
pages=soup.findall('span',{'class':'pagnDisabled'})
if len(pages) == 0:
    print 'None'
elif len(pages):
    for i in range(2, len(pages) + 1):
       print i
```